# Rule-based string manipulation

Tags: string-manipulation

I am studying string manipulation.  I have a list of strings all members of which consist of 2 or 3 words followed by a 3 letter capital appreviation of the words, for example

```
str={A Big Cheese ABC}
```

I'd like to get two substrings:

```
str1={A Big Cheese}
```

and

```
str2={ABC}
```

Using UpperCaseQ returning "True" for three characters in a row would appear to be a first step.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You want to make a `StringPattern` and feed it to `StringReplace`

Comment: `str` is not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need a [string pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html) that matches your inputs.  The first part of your string `"A Big Cheese"`, can be matched by two underscores, `__`.  The last part is always three upper case letters in a row.  You can match any upper case letter with

```
caps = Alternatives @@ (ToUpperCase /@ Alphabet[])
```

[image]

You can see it work here,

```
StringMatchQ["A", caps]
(* True *)
```

To catch three capital letters in a row, you can join them using `~~`

```
StringMatchQ["ABC", caps ~~ caps ~~ caps]
(* True *)

StringMatchQ["AbC", caps ~~ caps ~~ caps]
(* False *)
```

Or you can use `Repeated`,

```
StringMatchQ["XYZ", Repeated[caps, {3}]]
(* True *)
```

Now that we have our pattern we can give it to `StringCases`.  You need to [name the patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamingPiecesOfPatterns.html) and apply a [transformation rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html)

```
StringCases["A Big Cheese ABC", a__ ~~ b : Repeated[caps, {3}] :> {a, b}]
(* {{"A Big Cheese ", "ABC"}} *)
```

You can wrap this up into a function, using `First` to remove the extra curly brackets,

```
splitSTRING["examine your zipper XYZ"]
(* {"examine your zipper ", "XYZ"} *)
```

### Edit

As march points out you don't have to use `Alternatives` to make a [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html), you could use `UpperCaseQ` to make a [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html):

```
StringCases["A Big Cheese ABC", 
 a__ ~~ b : Repeated[_?(UpperCaseQ), {3}] :> {a, b}]
(* {{"A Big Cheese ", "ABC"}} *)
```

Comment: Would not `Repeated[_?(UpperCaseQ), {3}]` work as well, rather than defining `caps`?

Comment: Yes indeed you can - I just have been using `Alternatives` a lot lately so that was my go-to solution.

Comment: Yeah okay, I didn't do it myself, so I wasn't sure if there was some pitfall there I just wasn't seeing.

Comment: A regex variation: `StringCases[{"A Big Cheese ABC", "examine your zipper XYZ"}, RegularExpression["((\\w|\\s)+) ([[:upper:]]{3})"] -> {"$1", "$3"}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input strings end with *a 3 letter capital abbreviation of the words*,
you can use `StringTake`:

```
StringTake["A Big Cheese ABC", {{1, -5}, -3}]
```

> {"A Big Cheese", "ABC"}

Answer (score 0):

a work around:

```
str1=StringJoin[Riffle[Most[Flatten[StringSplit[str]]], " "]]
```

and

```
str2=Last[Flatten[StringSplit[str]]]
```